# when can I use dot notation to access a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, notation

I am modifying somebody's code in the context of the 'gym'' environment and came across the use of the dot notation to access a dictionary. 
the following snippet shows that the dictionary in gym can use the notation but when I duplicate it it throws an error.

```
import gym
env = gym.Env
env = make('connectx', debug=True)
config = env.configuration
print(config)
print(config.timeout)
dct = {'timeout': 5, 'columns': 7, 'rows': 6, 'inarow': 4, 'steps': 1000}
print(dct.timeout)
```

this provides the following output:

```
{'timeout': 5, 'columns': 7, 'rows': 6, 'inarow': 4, 'steps': 1000}
5

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-45-674d59d34c55> in <module>
      6 print(config.timeout)
      7 dct = {'timeout': 5, 'columns': 7, 'rows': 6, 'inarow': 4, 'steps': 1000}
----> 8 print(dct.timeout)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

I am using Python 3. Can somebody explain please?
Thanks

Comment: `dict` values can not be accessed using dot notation. `config` is probably not a `dict` - use `type(config)` to figure out what it is.

Comment: I guess you are quite used to javascript syntax and semantics?

Comment: You are correct config is a <class 'kaggle_environments.utils.Struct'> Thank you for that.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike JavaScript objects, Python dicts don't natively support dot notation.

Try [**Dotsi**](https://github.com/polydojo/dotsi/), [Addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict) or a similar library. Here's a quick snippet of Dotsi in action:

```py
>>> import dotsi
>>> 
>>> d = dotsi.Dict({"foo": {"bar": "baz"}})     # Basic
>>> d.foo.bar
'baz'
>>> d.users = [{"id": 0, "name": "Alice"}]      # In list
>>> d.users[0].name
'Alice'
>>>
```

Disclosure: I'm Dotsi's author.

Answer (score 2):

In python you cannot access a dictionnary value with `dict.key`, you need to use `dict[key]`

Example :

```
d = {"foo": 2}
print(d["foo"])
# 2

key = foo
print(d[key])
# 2

print(d.foo)
# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'foo'

print(d.key)
# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'key'
```

If you really want to use the **dot notation**, you can use a class (your `config` is probably a class instance by the way):

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "bar"

a = MyClass()
print(a.foo)
# bar
```

Comment: I normally DO use dict[key] but the code I am altering seems to use the dot notation successfully and I wanted to understand how.

Comment: cf in my answer, on the part about classes : you can use the dot notation with class instances